# Windows Forms C# retrieving SQL data using WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Bit of a hobbyist coder (and Novice) so I appreciate I may be approaching this in the wrong way so any advice on changing my approach would also be appreciated.

The idea is to have a "More Details" button on a form, that will open another form showing the customers contact details retrieved from a SQL table. The table called 'Project_Info' contains all of the contact/address data, using a 'Project' ID as the unique identifier.

The code for the button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WIN-M9TBGRD70BU;Initial Catalog=Disk_Tracker;User ID=Tracker;Password=********");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Project_Info WHERE (Project = 'P3890T')", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    {
        this.Hide();
        TRACK_10_PI T10 = new TRACK_10_PI();
        T10.Show();
    }
}
```

The new form `TRACK_10_PI` opens but always displays the data from the top row rather than as the WHERE clause has specified.

The reason I want the data retrieved from a database rather than simply hard coding it to the page is to accommodate possible changes to the information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could the problem be in `TRACK_10_PI`?

Comment: What results do you get when you run the query directly against the database using your favourite database querying tool?

Comment: where you are consuming data filled in dt.?

Comment: it would appear that TRACK_10_PI has it's own query that doesn't include a WHERE clause. I don't see where you're using the datatable that you populate here.

Comment: where are you executing the query?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you will use usinngs, so you don't Need to dispose expliciet.
Place a `datagridview` on your form which is filled by your code. You can parameterize your instantiation of your form. Now you have to fill the datasouse in `TRACK_10_PI`.

Example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WIN-M9TBGRD70BU;Initial Catalog=Disk_Tracker;User ID=Tracker;Password=********"))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Project_Info WHERE (Project = 'P3890T')", con))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        this.Hide();
        TRACK_10_PI T10 = new TRACK_10_PI(sda);
        T10.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting you're not passing the newly created `dt` in the form `TRACK_10_PI`. I don't see any problem with you code except that you should dispose the `SqlConnection` and the `SqlDataAdapter` objects.